# Storing a value created from user input inside a loop for use in other iterations of the loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a program that simulates driving a car. In my program, I have the following loop to allow the user to "drive" however many miles they wish:

```
public void run() {
    do {
        System.out.println("How many miles would you like to drive?");
        int userInput = scanner.nextInt();
        if (userInput > 360) {
            System.out.println("You don't have enough fuel to drive that far! Please try again.");
            run();
        }
        System.out.println("You are driving: " + userInput + " miles.");
        try {   
            for(int c = 0; c < parts.size(); c++){
                parts.get(c).function(userInput);
            }
        } catch (BreakdownException e) {        
        }
    } while (getBoolean("Keep driving?"));
```

I would like to take the `userInput` variable and save it so that I can keep track of how many miles are in the gas tank. This is the code I currently have for that:

```
public void function(int milesDriven) throws BreakdownException {
            
    int mpg = 30;
    int gallons = 12;
    int totalMiles = gallons * mpg;
    int milesLeft = totalMiles - milesDriven;
        
    if(milesLeft <= 0) {
        throw new BreakdownException("You ran out of fuel!");

    } else if (milesLeft <= (totalMiles / 4)) {
        if (getBoolean("You are low on fuel! Refuel?")) {
            milesLeft = gallons * mpg;
            System.out.println("You now have enough fuel to travel " + totalMiles + " miles.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("You now have enough fuel to travel " + milesLeft + " miles.");
    }
}
```

Currently, each time the loop in the first code block runs, the value for `milesDriven` in the second code block resets. Thus, every time the user "drives", their gas tank automatically refills. Is there a way I can store the `userInput` value so that it retains between loops?

Thanks!

Comment: The declarations of any variables you don't want reset on each call to `function` need to be moved outside of `function` into the surrounding class, where they will be accessible to any method of that class.   The relevant topic you should research is "scope of variables".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change things up too much, one easy way would be to simply accumulate the user input with another variable, and pass that value into the `function` method instead of the user input that updates on each loop. So for example, outside of the do-while loop you would have:

```
int milesDriven = 0;
```

Then, each time the user gives a new input, add that value to the miles driven:

```
int userInput = scanner.nextInt();
milesDriven += userInput;
```

And finally pass that value into the `function` method instead of the user input:

```
parts.get(c).function(milesDriven);
```